# HTML & CSS page formatting error

Tags: html, styles, head

it have made an css and html file which gives and right side margin ,header and footer

but the problem is that when the page is minimized the scroll bar comes i dont want this scroll bar when the page is minimized so please give me some suggestion

Comment: Please show some of the CSS & HTML so others can help troubleshoot. Also, clarify "minimized". Because when I think minimized, I think of minimizing a window to the taskbar (aka, the page isn't visible anyway).

Answer (score 1):

```
div 
{
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

change overflow property to hidden

Answer (score 0):

Use overflow hidden, see: http://wiki.futuretoby.com/How_to_Remove_the_Scrollbar_from_your_Browser_Window